# How to fix qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped Segmentation fault

Tags: raspbian-buster, qemu

I don't know if this is a Noob question, and if it is I'm sorry. But can anyone tell me how to fix `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault`

I get this from trying to chroot into another system.

Comment: Hi @SkywalkerSW5, Ah, let me see. If you break from a small jail to a bigger one, Rpi's 32 bit RAM pointer might hit the wall and drop dead.

Comment: Simply `chroot` into another system does not invoke `qemu`. I don't understand what you have made.